# How to program a Download/Save button to a SWF Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok, so I'm working on an Adobe Flash ActionScript 3 file. I programmed a hyperlink to an external pdf file, but I was told that that's a no-go. The file needs to be included inside the SWF, and clicking a button should let the user save it on his computer. I have no clue how that should work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FileReference.download(), you can read the documentation. You don't need to include the file in the SWF.

[FileReference documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download%28%29)